# What is the meaning of じゃな?

Tags: grammar

I am watching an anime and there are two old characters (an old witch and an old dragon) that always end their sentences with じゃな

I'm quite sure it's something from 古典語. I know that  じゃ is equivalent to the modern だ. What about the な?

Does it have the same meaning as the normal な 終助詞?

Comment: You've never heard ～（だ）な in more modern speech?

Comment: I suspected it meant だな. But their pronunciation is very light and short so I wanted someone to confirm it. They don't say じゃなぁ。。。 you know?